# How to check a request.user with raw sql in Django

Tags: sql, django, rawsql

I want to get data about a Student which is currently logged in

Here is my code:

```
def profile(request):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    a = request.user.id
    cursor.execute("SELECT * from Student WHERE ID = a ")

    data = dictfetchall(cursor)
    return render(request, 'personal.html', {'data': data})
```

in table Student attribute ID is connected with attribute id in tha table auth_user
Is it even possible to check? I know that with ORM it is easy to do, but I need to use raw sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You work with a parameter, so:

```
def profile(request):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Student WHERE ID = %s', [request.user.id])
        data = dictfetchall(cursor)
    return render(request, 'personal.html', {'data': data})
```

however using raw queries is often *not* a good idea.